# Unused argument error using stopwords in R

Tags: r, tm, stop-words

I am trying to clean and process post data from twitter. The initial corpus produces the following after cleaning:
`text_corpus[[1]]$content`
[1] "I actually would love if my Mad Scientist was drawn in a Gorillaz-style fanart..."
`text_corpus[[5]]$content`
[1] "I actually would love if my Mad Scientist was drawn in a Gorillaz-style fanart..."

When I process the text further I get this error:

> Error in stopwords(kind = "SMART") : unused argument (kind = "SMART")

This is the code I use to remove stop words

```
  tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>% 
  tm_map(removeNumbers) %>% 
  tm_map(removePunctuation) %>% 
  tm_map(removeWords, stopwords(kind = "SMART")) %>% 
  tm_map(stemDocument) %>% 
  tm_map(stripWhitespace)
```

Retrieving the content of the text_corpus after this results in the exact same text as above. Have I done something wrong? Is there anything else I can use to remove stopwords?
Thanks

Comment: Does this help: `tm_map(FUN = removeWords, stopwords(kind = 'SMART'))`? The difference to your code is `... (FUN = ...` which tells `tm_map` which of the arguments is the mapping function and which arguments can be handed on to where they might be needed.

Comment: Looks like you loaded the library stopwords after loading tm. Try using `tm_map(removeWords, tm::stopwords(kind = "SMART"))` or if you want to use the stopwords package: `tm_map(removeWords, stopwords::stopwords(source = "smart"))`